# Can't import NLTK into Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, jupyter-notebook, nltk

I'm pretty new to python, Jupyter notebook, Tensorflow, and that whole lot in general. I'm getting started with a machine learning project. I've gotten to the point where I want to import "nltk" into my thing. It doesn't work. I've installed nltk with pip, and conda, and everything, in my terminal. When I do it again in the notebook, it says I've already installed it, which is correct. But when I try to import it it gives me a `ModuleNotFoundError`:

[image: 1]

I'm on a macbook, by the way. Any help?

Comment: Are you sure your terminal is in the same environment as the Jupyter notebook?

Comment: I'm not sure because I don't quite know what that means. :/. Does that mean opening a terminal from Jupyter Notebook directly? I tried doing that and installing nltk from there and it said "solving environment: done" but I tried importing it into my project and it still didn't work. Not sure if that is what you are referencing though.

Comment: are you using Anaconda ? if yes open Anaconda Navigator > Environments > search and install NLTK from there

Comment: I don't know much about Jupyter, This is a quick introduction of virtual environments though: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

Comment: @Thulfiqar I launched jupyter notebook from the anaconda navigator and it works now. thank you :)

Comment: glad to hear that :-)

Answer (score 1):

Going forward you can follow these steps (through terminal) so that same issues don't crop up again.

1. Create a conda environment if it's not already done

   `conda create -n py3_env python=3.8`
2. Get into the conda environment

   `conda activate py3_env`
3. Install ipykernel

   `conda install ipykernel`
4. Link the kernel to this conda env

   `ipython kernel install --user --name=py3_env`
5. Deactivate the conda environment

   `conda deactivate`

Now, when you open jupyter, you can select this kernel from the dropdown menu *kernel* >> *Change kernel*. Now, all the packages you've installed in this conda environment would be available in jupyter as well. E.g. you can install nltk in this environment in the following way:

```
conda activate py3_env
pip install nltk
conda deactivate
```